# 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

I am using gulp in my application.

1. installed gulp
2. put the npm script
3. run the script by using "npm start"

Got the error:-
**> start

> node_modules/.bin/gulp watch
> 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.**

In package.json to start the script:-
"scripts": {
"start": "node_modules/.bin/gulp watch"
},

Kindly help me to fix this issue.
Thank you

Comment: Try with `"./node_modules/.bin/gulp watch"` ?

Comment: I tried it. but won't worked. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When working with npm packages you do not need to specify a path to executable in node_modules. Try the following setup:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp watch"
  },
```

Make sure that gulp is present in dependencies as well.

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: It worked after removing the specif path. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect !. Worked for me too.

Comment: Perfect, worked for me too!
In my case I changed "node_modules/.bin/rimraf wwwroot/dist && webpack" to
"rimraf wwwroot/dist && webpack"

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem while working on React/NextJs project. The way I solved it is by specifying a direct path for the scripts in the package.json folder as follows:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "C:/Users/username/myFolder/NextjsProjectFolder/node_modules/.bin/next dev",
"build": "C:/Users/username/myFolder/NextjsProjectFolder/node_modules/.bin/next build",
"start": "C:/Users/username/myFolder/NextjsProjectFolder/node_modules/.bin/next start",
```

},

Perhaps, this could be helpful to someone working on Nextjs project.